# What Sci-fi film scores and soundtracks have won an Oscar?

Tags: movie, science-fiction-genre, music

Are there any sci-fi films whose musical score or soundtrack went on to win an Academy Award for best musical score? *The Fountain* comes to mind as having been nominated for a Golden Globe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1977 - Star Wars
1982 - E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial

Both by John Williams.

A number of others have been nominated; most recently:
Avatar (2009), Wall-e (2008), A.I. (2001)

Comment: Star Wars beat out *Close Encounters of the Third Kind* to win in 1977.  *Star Trek the Motion Picture*, *The Empire Strikes Back*, *Return of the Jedi*, *Aliens*, *ST: IV*, *Apollo 13*, *Men in Black*, *AI: Artificial Intelligence*, and *Planet of the Apes* (the original) were also nominated in other years. *Ghostbusters*, *Armageddon*, *Wall-e* and *Back to the Future* were nominated for Best Song.

Comment: 2009 Moon - Has great soundtrack by Clint Mansell, won BAFTA not Oscar

Comment: John Williams is a genius!

Answer (score 8):

John Williams won [Best Original Score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Award_for_Best_Original_Score) for Star Wars in 1977 and again for E. T. in 1982.